# Finding the pdf of a random variable generating from another random variable with defined pdf

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

Initially, there is a random variable $X$ (non-negative) with distribution function:
$$P(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$
Now we randomly generate $X$ and, then, form sets of $N$ values of this variable: $(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_N)$

And for each set, we define, for example, $$S = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N x_k^2$$
$S$ is then a new random variable. My question is: **How to find the pdf of this new random variable**?

Comment: instead of $n_k$ in your last formula, do you mean $x_k$?

Comment: @gt6989b yes, i've corrected that. Thank you.

Comment: i think squares of exponentials are from a generalized Gamma distribution, not sure if it is closed under sums though

Comment: What you call a "distribution function" is more precisely a probability density function. And you should mention that it's for $x\ge0. \qquad$

Answer (score 1):

**Comments;** Your Question is a possible duplicate of [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1092528/the-density-of-the-square-of-the-exponentially-distributed-random-variable), where a method is shown to get the answer, but not the answer itself.

You mention simulation: Here are results from a simulation in R of 100,000
realizations of $X^2,$ where $X \sim \mathsf{Exp}(\text{rate}\, \lambda = 1/3)$ and
$n = 5.$  Your reason for simulation is unclear; perhaps you want to
see if theoretical and simulated answers agree.

Of course, if $n$ is large enough, this sum of independent random
variables will be approximately normal. With $m = 100000$ the mean and
SD should be accurate to a couple of significant digits.

```
set.seed(309) # retain for exactly same simulation; delete for fresh run
m = 10^5; n = 5; lam = 1/3
x = rexp(m*n, lam)
MAT = matrix(x^2, nrow=m)  # each row of matrix is sample of size n
s = rowMeans(MAT)
mean(s);  sd(s)
## 17.90796
## 17.83484
hist(s, prob=T, br=100, ylim=c(0,.05), col="skyblue2", main="")
lines(density(s, from=0, to=300), lwd=2, col="darkgreen")
```

[image]

Comment: Something like `plot(density(s, from=0, to=100))` might give an indication of the bottom end of the distribution, e.g. a mode just over $5$ - well below the mean of $2\lambda^{-2}=18$ but well above $0$

Comment: @Henry: Thanks much. I improved the histogram by increasing the number of bins. R's KDE (now overlaid in my figure) seems to work well here, but I have learned not to trust it entirely near the end of the support of a distribution.

Comment: It turns out that the standard deviation of $X^2$ is $2\lambda^{-2}\sqrt{\frac{5}{n}}$ so in your example also $18$

Answer (score 1):

Since $x_1^2$ has characteristic function $\phi(t):=\int_0^\infty\lambda\exp(itx^2-\lambda x)dx$, $S$ has characteristic function $\phi^N(\frac{t}{N})$, making its pdf $\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{2\pi}\phi^N(\frac{t}{N})e^{-itx}dt$. I doubt this has a nice expression, though of course the CLT gives a good approximation for large $N$. We have $\mathbb{E}x_1^k=k!\lambda^{-k}$, so $x_1^2$ has mean $2\lambda^{-2}$ and variance $20\lambda^{-4}$. Thus $S$ has the same mean and $N^{-1}$ times as much variance.